# discord.py multiple arguments?

Tags: python, discord

how do I have multiple args in one command in discord.py?

for example
`user: /say string`
`bot: string`

or
`user: /repeat integer`
`bot: (repeats something a number of times)`

or
`user: /kill @mention`
`bot: user killed @mention`

and is there a way where you can put them all into one command?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. Do you have some code demonstrating your current usage of slash commands and what you want to change about it? I don't see any of your commands having multiple arguments in your three examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this code should solve your problem:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, string: str):
    await ctx.send(string)

@bot.command()
async def repeat(ctx, integer: int):
    for i in range(integer):
        await ctx.send("Repeating something")

@bot.command()
async def kill(ctx, mention: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send("user killed {}".format(mention))
```

Comment: thanks! you just forgot to add `await`

Comment: another problem is that for the string one it can only send 1 word